# UIImage displaying incorrectly in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an XIB file that looks like this:

[image: XIB Screenshot]

As you can see I have a UIImageView at the bottom of the view, note its all contained within the view.

However, when I run the code which places a UIImage in the view, I get this:

[image: Running]

Here is the image I am trying to display:

[Image](http://dblog.com.au/wp-content/elephant.jpg)

Why does it go off the bottom of the screen? I've seen similar behaviour in some of my other projects, whats going on?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IB, for the top-level view, for the Simulated User Interface Elements, set the Top Bar to be one of the Navigation Bar options. Understand, you will!

Answer (score 0):

hi jack you also do that change view size from interface builder  like 320 &460